# PS - Add a column of the current date

Tags: powershell

Thank you for all your help in advance.  I am writing a Script that will locate any folders older than 30 days and remove them (that is in another function).  I am having some problems storing those folder names in CSV.  I can store the name, LastWriteTime, but I want to add a new column that will state the "Deleted Time" which I assume can use Get-Date.  I am not sure how to accomplish that.  Can someone help me?
Thank you

```
$CoryDeletedFolders += Get-ChildItem "C:\Test\Test 2" -Directory | 
    #Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30))} |
    Select-Object Name, LastWriteTime |
    Export-Csv -Path 'C:\APPS\Delete Folder - Cory\CoryDeletedFolders.csv' -Append
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to explicitly [creating custom objects with the `[pscustomobject]@{}` notation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67886945/712649), `Select-Object` can also *calculate* new properties for you:

```
$CoryDeletedFolders += Get-ChildItem "C:\Test\Test 2" -Directory | 
    Select-Object Name, LastWriteTime, @{Name='DeletedTime';Expression={Get-Date}} | ...
```

The property definition `@{Name='DeletedTime';Expression={Get-Date}}` will create a new property named `DeletedTime` with the value of whatever `Get-Date` returned when the pipeline ran

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom object with added date and using items from `Get-ChildItem`

More on PSCustomObject: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject?view=powershell-5.1

```
$CoryDeletedFolders += Get-ChildItem "C:\temp" | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name = $_.Name
            LastWriteTime = $_.LastWriteTime
            DeletedTime = (Get-Date).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss")
        }
    } |
    Export-Csv -Path 'C:\APPS\Delete Folder - Cory\CoryDeletedFolders.csv' -Append
```